# Camera access in Qt widget

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm not able to access android camera in my Qt widget application..i tried QCamera API it's returning error in Debug shown as below

> D libCamera.so: ../Camera/main.cpp:13 (int main(int, char**)): hi W
>   linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W linker  :
>   /data/data/org.qtproject.example/qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so:
>   unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81 W libCamera.so: (null):0 ((null)):
>   The video surface is not compatible with any format supported by the
>   camera V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@42a0529 D Camera  : app passed NULL
>   surface D Camera  : app passed NULL surface W libCamera.so: (null):0
>   ((null)): The video surface is not compatible with any format
>   supported by the camera D Camera  : app passed NULL surface D Camera 
>   : app passed NULL surface
>
> "org.qtproject.example" died.

Comment: Not easy to judge without your specific code. Please share [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**Sir its something like, when i run the app in my android device my device camera should be accessed/opened...**

Here's my camera.cpp code--->

If any corrections please let me know?

## include "camera.h"

## include "ui_camera.h"

Camera::Camera(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Camera)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

```
camera = new QCamera;
viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder;
camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);
viewfinder->show();

camera->start(); // to start the viewfinder

imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);
camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureStillImage);
camera->start(); // Viewfinder frames start flowing

camera->searchAndLock();

imageCapture->capture();

camera->unlock();
```

}

Comment: QCamera do not works on android, you need to use the Camera from qml to control the camera.